# Compile-time conditional protocol conformance in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, conditional-compilation

I have a Swift class that, under certain compile-time conditions, should implement a certain protocol. I expected that conditional complication `#if` checks would work, with something like this:

```swift
class MyClass
#if SOME_COMPILE_TIME_CHECK
: SomeProtocol
#endif
{
  // ...

  #if SOME_COMPILE_TIME_CHECK
  func someMethodToImplementSomeProtocol() { }
  #endif
}
```

This does not work. The compiler tries to compile each conditional block as a series of statements. But the block `: SomeProtocol` does not parse as a series of statements.

Is there another way to express this? For example, is there a statement-level way to express that "`MyClass` implements `SomeProtocol`"?

Comment: define a MyClass extension to conform to the protocol and wrap all of that in your compile time check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in an extension:

```
#if SOME_COMPILE_TIME_CHECK
extension MyClass : SomeProtocol {
    func someMethodToImplementSomeProtocol() { }
}
#endif
```